# Any way to get generic T class object from static method(without calling constructor)?

Tags: java

Here is how code looks like

```
abstract class A<T>
{
   T panel;
   public A()
   {
      code here does something I don't want to be called, and I can't overload it)
   }
   abstract T createPanel();
}
...
class B extends A<RealClass>
{
   ...
   @Override
   RealClass createPanel()
   { 
      return new RealClass();
   }
}
```

What I want is to be able to receive **RealClass.class** from some method, having only `Class cls = B.class;` and without calling any costructors of B.

Is that possible in any way?

Comment: Where does `static` come into play here?

Comment: all methods I found here are from B() constructor(so they need B class instance, unlike static method). And I want to have static method in class A that takes its child class class object as parameter and returns child class T class object(for B it is RealClass.class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want is to be able to receive RealClass.class from some method, having only Class cls = B.class;

You need to get the generic of the parent.

```
Type type = cls.getGenericSuperClass();
if (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
    ParameterizedType ptype = (ParameterizedType) type;
    Class genericType = (Class) ptype.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}
```

This type is only available as the information is included in the byte code.  This wouldn't work if you had

```
class B<T> extends A<T>
```

as the `getActualTypeArguments()[0]` would return a `T` Type.

Comment: Thank you!!! That worked!
ps plz fix cls.getGenericSuperClass -> cls.getGenericSuperclass

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is actually one of the cases where you can do it.

```
(Class<?>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
     .getActualTypeArguments()[0]
```

ought to do it.  Alternately, if you can use third-party libraries, Guava's `TypeToken` would make this something like `(Class<T>) new TypeToken<T>(getClass()).getType()`.

The reason you can do this is that `A<RealClass>` is hardcoded -- it's a concrete type parameter, and unlike the generic types of *objects*, the generic types and supertypes of *classes* are preserved through type erasure.